# Diagonalizable over $\mathbb{Z}/p$ versus over the algebraic closure

Tags: linear-algebra

If $k$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}/p$ for a prime $p$, and $M$ is a matrix in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}/p)$. The canonical inclusion $\mathbb{Z}/p \subset k$ lets us view $M$ as a matrix over $k$.

Is $M$ diagonalizable over $\mathbb{Z}/p$ $\iff$ $M$ is diagonalizable over $k$?

Going left to right seems to be true, since if $P^{-1}MP$ is diagonalizable when $P \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z}/p)$, then including these matrices into $GL_n(k)$ gives a diagonalization of $M$ over $k$. But what about the other direction? If it's not true, is there an addition condition one could impose that would make it true?

Comment: The minimal polynomial must be separable and split completely.

Comment: I think an argument using $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ would carry over, if not directly, then at least in spirit (as in, you can't use the exact same numbers, obviously, but more or less the same argument ought to work).

Comment: Since $k$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$ - a field of characteristic $p>0$ there can be no inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq k$.

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ is *not* congruent 1 mod 4, the equation $x^2+1=0$ does *not* admit a solution in $\mathbb F_p$, hence the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$
is *not* diagonizable over $\mathbb F_p$. It *is* diagonalizable over the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ however, since $x^2+1 = (x-i)(x+i)$ in $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$.

As linear algebra tells you: If you want a matrix $A$ over a field $K$ to be diagonalizable, its characteristic polynomial has to split completely and the dimensions of the respective eigenspaces have to match the algebraic multiplicities. This is an *if and only if*, so it is not clear to me what "additional condition" you are asking for.

In fact, by a mere counting argument we can deduce that in every finite field $F$ of odd characteristic there is an element $t$, which is *not* a square, ie. for which $x^2-t$ does *not* admit a solution in $F$. Thus the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&t\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$
is *not* diagonizable over $F$, while it is over $\overline{F}$. So your there cannot be a criterion making your equivalence hold true in general (unless maybe p=2, but we can find a counterexample there too).

Comment: For $p=2$, we can consider $\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, whose characteristic polynomial is $X^2+X+1$, which has no root in $\mathbb{F}_2$. In general, over a finite field, there are polynomials with no root of any degree $n >1$ (and in fact, irreducible polynomials of any degree).